# How to find my StackExchange profile link

Tags: discussion, profile-page, network-profile, merge-accounts

A bit lost sorry, can't find the answer.

Obviously, I've 2 SE accounts and I want to merge them. Problem is when I fill in the merge form, I need to provide the links of my profiles.

I thought those links are:

> https://stackexchange.com/users/#id#/#nickname#

But obviously, I'm wrong as the merge form returns:

> oops, this isn't a link to a valid profile.

So, simple question: where can I get the links of my profiles?

Comment: Note the `nickname` part is not necessary, you can put any string there.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you missed the `meta.` in the URL since the Network profile ID is different from your MSE account ID. I guess you need the latter to make it work.

---

To get the right ID:

Click on the profile image in the top bar:

> [image: click here]

or search your user from the [users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users):

> [image: click here]

Use the URL of the page you end up:

> [image: link]

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Hofman, but I don't see where I did something wrong. Because the URL format I gave in my question has the exact same format, except the "meta".

Comment: Yes, I guess so. @romu

Comment: Is the "meta" mandatory?

Comment: If that causes you to point to an invalid profile, yes it is.

Comment: I added meta, but it is useless, still same error message "oops! this isn't a link to a valid profile".

Comment: I added meta, but it is useless, still same error message "oops! this isn't a link to a valid profile".   In fact,  this error message is valid since with the extra meta in the link I got a "404 page not found". But without the meta, I can reach my account in a browser without any problem.  So the error message saying the link to be invalid is simply wrong.